# how to detect active slide Swiperjs and do something in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have an javascript object, in this object I have events and methods and im using Swiperjs for the carousel.

I have click events on carousel slides. The click on a specific slide class displays infos inside other divs.

Now I want to display these infos only when the specific slide is active, not by clicking on it. I've tried realIndex and activeIndex but it always returns 0 and can't manipulate it... In what way can I do that ?

HTML

```
<!-- Swiper -->
          <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide webagency" style="background-image:url(assets/images/backgrounds/WebAgency.jpg)"></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide noumea-touring" style="background-image:url(assets/images/backgrounds/Noumea-touring.jpg)"></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide bikemap" style="background-image:url(assets/images/backgrounds/Bikemap.jpg)"></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide jeanforteroche" style="background-image:url(assets/images/backgrounds/Jeanforteroche.jpg)"></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide youjudge" style="background-image:url(assets/images/backgrounds/Youjudge.jpg)"></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide margotdemir" style="background-image:url(assets/images/backgrounds/margotdemir.jpg)"></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide tabac" style="background-image:url(assets/images/backgrounds/Tabac.jpg)"></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide todolist" style="background-image:url(assets/images/backgrounds/Todolist.jpg)"></div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
class Works {
constructor() {

    // Variables
    this.webagency = $('.webagency');


    //Events
    this.webagency.click(this.webagencyItem.bind(this));}
```

and the method

```
    // Methods
webagencyItem() {
    this.content.show();
    this.title.html("Webagency (Projet 1 OCR)");
    this.text.html("Intégration d'une maquette graphique en HTML CSS sans framework.");
    this.url.show();
    this.url.attr("href", "http://projetocferres.com/");
    this.code.show();
    this.code.attr("href", "https://github.com/eferdeve/Webagency");
    this.card.css('box-shadow', 'inset 0px 0px 25px #6e6c6d');
}
```

and the js to initialize swiperjs

```
var myswiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
effect: 'flip',
grabCursor: true,
pagination: {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
},
navigation: {
  nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
},
```

});

Comment: I think in this case ```myswiper.activeIndex``` returns the active index of the slide.

Comment: Check here: https://prnt.sc/w410yp

Comment: myswiper.activeIndex always returns 0 when I console.log